# Is it possible to run CodedUI test without installing VS? How?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I want to run my coded UI test on a testing machine, but I wish If I can escape from installing VS2012 on my Test machine. Is there any any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2015/04/08/automation-runner-running-tests-without-visual-studio/) blog you only need to install the test controller software on a machine: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2015/04/08/automation-runner-running-tests-without-visual-studio/

Also there is a tool that wraps around VSTEST.Console to simplify running tests without VS:

> Automation Runner only Requires Test Controller to be installed on the
>   running machine – No MTM or Visual Studio Required.

Comment: Thanks Niels, I will try this out and see how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

I used VS Test Agent and it ran the tests for me without Visual studio